# Global Git Config Properties for all Remotes

Tags: git, config, gerrit, git-config

I wanted to know if this was possible and if so, how to configure it.

At work, we utilize git repositories.  We have a bunch of repositories and then use gerrit for code reviews.  We have a series of branches in each repository.  We utilize .git/config files to indicate specific properties such as the "receivepack" to call out properties such as the --reviewer(s) for the code review.  This particular piece is repeated for each remote branch within each repository and is the same in each.  Every time we get a new team member, we have to update everything.  Is there a way to have this call a global property or be dynamic enough to update it in one location and have the .git/config to pull it down when we do a push?

Here is an example of a config file we are using.  The "remote" branch is repeated in each git repository we have and in most repositories, there are numerous remote branches forcing us to revise dozens of e-mail addresses in dozens of locations to keep things up to date.

```
[core]
repositoryformatversion = 0
filemode = false
bare = false
logallrefupdates = true
symlinks = false
ignorecase = true
hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
[remote "origin"]
    url = ssh://gerrit/repo1
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[branch "int"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/int

[remote "gerrit"]
    url = ssh://gerrit/repo1
    receivepack = git receive-pack --reviewer=person@email.com --reviewer=personagain@email.com --reviewer=etc@email.com 
    push = HEAD:refs/for/int
```

Is it possible to use an alias to solve this problem?  That would be the ideal scenario and probably the cleanest in terms of maintenance and overhead.

Comment: Can you provide a sample `.git/config` file with the configuration you are describing? Why does it have to be updated on new team member?

Comment: How about updating the same in ~/.gitconfig file? Since all global properties are defined here.

Comment: What would be the syntax to add it to ~/.gitconfig?  I want to be able to update it in a single location, but primarily just the "receivepack" portion as that is the only thing that gets updated.

Comment: I suppose I could add an alias that performs a commit with the 'receivepack' function?  I am just confused on the best method for this.

Comment: Does anyone know of a legitimate method to accomplish this?  If I was to use an alias for "push" for instance, could I use the alias of "push-custom" and then have it do a push receivepack = blah and then when I go to push, I could do git push-custom gerrit?  Or is there a better way to do this?